# Linq to Entity Group by Date

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Done a lot of research but still having a tough one with this. Consider a database which has a transactions table of "CreatedOn", "Amount", "Type". I need to be able to do an entity query to get transactions of a certain type grouped together by different date granularities (month / day etc).

So imagine a table with:

```
2011/1/22   $300   Deposit
2011/2/18   $340   Deposit
2011/3/6   $200    Other
2011/3/6   $100    Deposit
2011/3/7   $50     Deposit
```

I could have a query which would pull all deposits grouped by month so it could yield:

```
2011-1 $300 1deposit
2011-2 $340 1deposit
2011-3 $150 2deposits
```

How would I then adapt this query to be by day rather than month?

Here's my current block of code but I get an inner linq exception

> Can't group on A1

```
var result = context.TransactionEntities.Where(d => d.Type == "Deposit")                                     
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.CreatedOn.Year, g.CreatedOn.Month })
                    .Select(g => new
                           {
                                 DateKey = g.Key,
                                 TotalDepositAmount = g.Sum(d => d.Amount),
                                 DepositCount = g.Count()
                            }).ToList();
```

Note: I am currently using the MySql connector and I've read possibly this is a bug?

Comment: I am trying to achieve exactly similar functionality in LINQ to EF but no success yet, did u get it working?

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<DateTime, object> groupByClause;
if (groupByDay) groupByClause = date => date.Date;
else if (groupByMonth) groupByClause = date => new { date.Year, date.Month};
else throw new NotSupportedException("Some option should be chosen");

var result = data.Where(d => d.Type == "Deposit")
                 .GroupBy(groupByClause)
                 .Select(g => new { DateKey = g.Key,
                                    TotalDepositAmount = g.Sum(d => d.Amount),
                                    DepositCount = g.Count(),
                 });
```

Of course this should be checked whether linq-2-entities will accept it.

Comment: hey, this looks very solid. I tried it and get the inner exception 'Can't group on A1'.  My query looks like:

var result = context.TransactionEntities.Where(d => d.Type == "Deposit").GroupBy(g => new { g.CreatedOn.Year, g.CreatedOn.Month })                                     .Select(g => new { 
DateKey = g.Key, 
TotalDepositAmount = g.Sum(d => d.Amount), 
DepositCount = g.Count() }).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Check the code mentioned in my question: [Group by Weeks in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059737/group-by-weeks-in-linq-to-entities).  It shows how you can group your data by days and months. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in MySQL connector. My solution for that was to place `.ToList()` just before `.GroupBy()`.

Comment: Yah, problem with this is ToList executes the SQL query and the group by will then be local so it can end up pulling a ton of data.

Comment: @nextgenneo Yes, but it's better than nothing :)