# How to Datetime Groupby Month with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda, webforms

My code here:

```
var query = context.Article.GroupBy(x=>x.CreateDate.Value.Month)
```

is not working

For example

```
January 2017
February 2017
March 2017
```

Comment: var query = context.Article.GroupBy(x=> new {Month = x.CreateDate.Value.Month})
check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9886447/1882537

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by your collection using month and year and then loop through the grouped items.

```
var articlesGrouped = context.Article
                             .Where(g=>g.CreatedTime!=null)
                             .GroupBy(x => new { Month = x.CreatedTime.Value.Month,
                                                 Year = x.CreatedTime.Value.Year })
                             .ToList();
```

This will give you the articles grouped by month and year.

The Month value is the number. If you want the correspnding name, you can use a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object.

```
var dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
foreach (var groupedItem in postGrouped)
{
    var month = dtfi.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(groupedItem.Key.Month)
    var year = groupedItem.Key.Year;
    //now you can loop through item 
    foreach (var article in groupedItem)
    {
        var title = article.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: var articlesGrouped = context.Article .Where (g => g.CreatedTime! = null) .GroupBy (x => yeni {Ay x.CreatedTime.Value.Month, Yıl = x.CreatedTime.Value.Year}) .ToList) ; Not working :/

Comment: What you mean "Not working" ? Are you getting an error ? What is happening ?

Comment: Sorry  I made a mistake its working Thanks a lot man