# get report group by weekly in c#

Tags: c#, linq, razor-pages, ef-core-5.0

In My project Enter data dayly
Now I want have sum of record weekly or group data weekly, I try many methods, but got some error like:

> .GroupBy(
> keySelector: d => __CurrentCulture_Calendar_0.GetWeekOfYear(
> time: d.ReportDate,
> rule: FirstDay,
> firstDayOfWeek: Saturday),
> elementSelector: d => d)'

This is my ViewModel (the same as Model)
public class DataReportViewModels
{

```
    public int TotalPCRTest { get; set; }
    public int TotalRapidTest { get; set; }
    public int PosPCRTest { get; set; }
    public int PosRapidTest { get; set; }
    public int PatientInCovid { get; set; }
    public int PatienPosInCovid { get; set; }
    public int PatientInICU { get; set; }
    public int TotalPosDeath { get; set; }
    public int TotalOutpatients { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
}
```

and in my PageModel

```
      public IList<DataReportViewModels> ReportViewModelsw{ get; set; }



    IQueryable<DataReportViewModels> dataw = _context.DataReports.GroupBy(d => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear
        (d.ReportDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Saturday))
.Select(dat => new DataReportViewModels
           {
               //ReportDate = dat.Key,
               
               TotalPCRTest = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalPCRTest),
               TotalRapidTest = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalRapidTest),
               PosPCRTest = dat.Sum(x => x.PosPCRTest),
               PosRapidTest = dat.Sum(x => x.PosRapidTest),
               PatientInCovid = dat.Sum(x => x.PatientInCovid),
               PatienPosInCovid = dat.Sum(x => x.PatienPosInCovid),
               PatientInICU = dat.Sum(x => x.PaatientInICU),
               TotalPosDeath = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalPosDeath),

               TotalOutpatients = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalOutpatients)
           }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReportDate);

        ReportViewModelsw = dataw.ToList();
```

***Update my query***

```
   var dataw = _context.DataReports.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id > 1).GroupBy(d =>

               // ReportDate = d.ReportDate,
               (d.ReportDate.Day - 10) / 7)
           .Select(dat => new DataReportViewModels
           {


               TotalPCRTest = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalPCRTest),
               TotalRapidTest = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalRapidTest),
               PosPCRTest = dat.Sum(x => x.PosPCRTest),
               PosRapidTest = dat.Sum(x => x.PosRapidTest),
               PatientInCovid = dat.Sum(x => x.PatientInCovid),
               PatienPosInCovid = dat.Sum(x => x.PatienPosInCovid),
               PatientInICU = dat.Sum(x => x.PaatientInICU),
               TotalPosDeath = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalPosDeath),
               TotalOutpatients = dat.Sum(x => x.TotalOutpatients)
           });
```

And my table is normal table

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <caption>weekly report</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportViewModelsw[0].TotalPCRTest)
                    </th>
      ...
          </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ReportViewModelsw)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalPCRTest)
                    </td>
                  ....
             </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Date time extention

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using LINQ to EF: which one? LINQ to EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: [Group by weeks in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1059737/120955)

Comment: @NetMage this is my package   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" /> in core 5.

Comment: You say "some error like" but don't actually show an error.

Comment: You are trying to invoke a dot net method (`GetWeekOfYear`) inside of a SQL statement. This is not possible. Each and every dotnet method that you can call, must be translated to SQL. This is the job to the EF provider. Your EF provider does not know how to translate `GetWeekOfYear`.

Comment: Thanks, I update my query with "Group by weeks in LINQ to Entities"  but in result I have 5 days together and then a day and then 9 days, I change day in grouping but only change grouping rang